# Content is not shown in the Email when using PHP `mail` Function

Tags: php, email

I have encountered a problem with the mail function I created based on the built-in PHP `mail()` function. When I log in to my Email-Manager, the email content field appears empty. I have checked the variables, and they seem to have the correct values. Here's the code snippet:

```
email("MyEmailAddress", "Nur ein test", "Hello XY, <br>This is just a test mail!", "roundmail");

function email($to, $subject, $body, $mode) {
    $subject = "XYZ: " . $subject;

    $body .= "<br><br><hr>Website - <a href='MyWebsite'>XYZ</a><br>";
    $body .= "<b>Wichtiger Hinweis:</b> Bitte hab Verständnis, dass auf diese E-Mail nicht geantwortet werden kann.<br>";
    $body .= "<br><a href='MyWebsite'>Impressum</a> &middot;
                <a href='MyWebsite'>Datenschutz</a>
             ";
    if($mode == "roundmail") {
        $id = user_id_from_email($to);
        $user_data_email = user_data($id, 'username', 'register_date');
        $hashEmail = hash('sha512', SALT."|".$id."|".PARAM1."|".PARAM2, false);
        $user_id_name_hashed = md5("user_id");
        $body .= "<br><a href='WebService&".$user_id_name_hashed."=".$hashEmail."'>E-Mail-Abonnement abbestellen</a>";
    }
    $headers  = "From: XYZ <MyEmailAccount>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UFT-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'                      . "\r\n";
    
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

### Edit

There were only some problems with my Email-Client, and nothing PHP-related.

Comment: Where are your other functions, like `user_id_from_email()` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to work fine, tested it with my setup, although I needed to change the roundmail condition to the follwing:

```
if($mode == "roundmail") {
    $id = 'to';// user_id_from_email($to);
    $user_data_email = 'stuff'; //user_data($id, 'username', 'register_date');
    $hashEmail = 'someHash'; //hash('sha512', SALT."|".$id."|".PARAM1."|".PARAM2, false);
    $user_id_name_hashed = md5("user_id");
    $body .= "<br><a href='WebService&".$user_id_name_hashed."=".$hashEmail."'>E-Mail-Abonnement abbestellen</a>";
}
```

Quick note: md5("user_id") will always yield the same result, you are hashing a string here, not an actual variable.

What does your email setup look like?

Comment: What changes did you made? I don't get it... :P And i know, that md5("user_id) will be always the same, this is my intention. The link is a deabo-Newsletter link and I don't want to make it too easy for hacker, so I crypted the GET-Variable, so noone knows, what this means

Comment: I think it's working now... Only arcor has some trouble at the moment, ty for all of you :)

Comment: in my post you can see the code I changed for me to work.